# Using Ace Editor with JSON Editor(by Jdorn) for AutoCompletion

Tags: javascript, json, editor, ace-editor

I am using `JSON` editor with `ace editor` plugin to display javaScript editable code box.
I have included required libs for `ace editor` and provided below code:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "format": "javascript"
}

JSONEditor.plugins.ace.theme = 'chrome';
```

And am able to get the editable code box ,I would like to use `Autocomplete` feature of Ace editor,any suggestions?